# Log in using different users

Tags: php, sql, database

Here is my code for log in:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("conn.php");
$qry=mysql_query("Select * from tblru");
$qry2=mysql_query("Select * from tbladmin");
$credentials=mysql_fetch_array($qry);
if(isset($_POST['login'])){

    if($_POST['user']==$credentials["user"]){
        if($_POST['pass']==$credentials["pass"]){   

        $_SESSION['user']=1;
        header("location:login.php");
        exit();
        }
        else{
            echo "<div style='position:absolute; right:230px; top:220px;'><b>WRONG PASSWORD<br>Re Input PASSWORD</b></div>";

        }
    }
    else{
        echo "<div style='position:absolute; right:230px; top:220px;'><b>WRONG USERNAME<br>Re Input Username</b></div>";
    }

}
?>
```

I need help here with this log in code. I have created several users, but my log in only reads the first user registered. Could you help me with my code to be able to log in with the other accounts?

Comment: Please indent your code properly so that it is easier for others to read it. All the whitespace is really unnecessary.

Comment: if i dont put the whites i cant post this question

Comment: `mysql_fetch_*()` functions only return a SINGLE row of the query results. You need to fetch in a loop... and what you're doing is rather pointless. It SHOULD be done with an sql `where` clause so the filtering is done in the database. As such, I suggest you learn about SQL where clauses, and about [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: Problem is you're not doing any type of loop.

Comment: can anyone suggest the loop i should make?

Comment: @DivineGraceBlanza: You only need 4 spaces to format text as code, and those are *not* printed then. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code.

Comment: i used
$qry=mysql_query("Select user from tblru where user=" . $_POST['user']); but it displays error when i fetch the data in $credentials

Comment: As another security-related note, please do not specify to the user that a username is invalid or that a password is invalid. Please combine them like such: "Invalid credentials: Username/password combination was invalid"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to fix your issue is to change your query to something like this:

```
$login = false;

if(!isset($_POST['user']) || !isset($_POST['pass'])) {
    // Something was missing
}
else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tblru WHERE user='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']) . "'"
         . " AND pass='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']) . "' LIMIT 1";

    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $credentials = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if($credentials !== false) {
        $login = true;
    }
}
```

From here, `$credentials` will either be your verified user or `FALSE`.

Now that that's been said, however, please note that the `mysql_*` family of functions are deprecated and will be removed in future versions of PHP. Please visit [this link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) to look at alternatives.

In addition, I noticed that you aren't hashing your password. This is a bad idea; storing your password in plaintext in the server makes it an inviting target. You can read more about it [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php).

Comment: it functions well now, but another is, how can i display the name of the account who logged in, in the other side??

Comment: Excellent, I'm glad it works! What you would do is set the account name, as well as other pieces of information, into the `$_SESSION` array. On other pages, you would call `session_start();` as your first line. You'd then be able to access variables on that session.

Comment: <?php
    include("conn.php");
    session_start();


    if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    header("location:index.php");
    exit();
    }
    }
    ?>

Comment: I GOT THAT on the admin.php, now i want to echo the user who logged in, in my previous script i just used echo $credentials['user'] but now, it doesnt appear

Comment: That looks alright. I'd probably start the session and check if the user is logged in in its own file (perhaps `sessioncheck.php`), then `require_once` it on each non-guest page.

Comment: i hope you dont mind how i post the codes, just really a begginer here

Comment: I don't mind too much, but some of this is starting to get outside the scope of the original question. Perhaps it'd be worth it to post a new question with the different problem? And to answer your other question, you'd `echo $_SESSION['user']`.

Comment: and by the way, before i get to the admin.php, it passes in the login.php which contains
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=admin.php?username=" . $user />

Comment: ok wait ill post another question, hope youll answer right away

Comment: Actually, I'm going to be going to the cinema to see this "leggo" flick. Best of luck in your project though! I'll see if I can help when I get back.